# Branch IO non-branch data is never cleared or reset onResume() or onReady()

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, branch.io

My Branch data does not "reset" after I read it in the initSession() callback. So if I am conditionally redirecting the user based on whether Branch contains the url parameter I am expecting to receive, the user will always be redirected because the link data always exists exactly as if I had just pressed the link. This happens until I manually kill the app. Here is my code:

In Android, creating a simple non-branch link :

```
 String uri = "myApp://?userId=100";
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

In Ionic, capturing the link data and directing to the DetailPage:

```
 this.platform.ready().then(() => {
handleBranch();
});

this.platform.resume.subscribe(() => {
      this.handleBranch();
    });

  private handleBranch() {
    const Branch = window['Branch'];
    Branch.initSession(data => {
      if (data['+non_branch_link']) {
        let urlStr = data['+non_branch_link'];
        const url = new URL(urlStr);
        this.nav.push(DetailPage, {userId: url.searchParams.get('userId')});
      }
    });
  }
```

I get the following data from Branch:

*{"+non_branch_link":"myApp://?userId=1950","+clicked_branch_link":false,"+is_first_session":false}*

But if I navigate out of the app, and back in, I get the same data, over and over.

*{"+non_branch_link":"myApp://?userId=1950","+clicked_branch_link":false,"+is_first_session":false}*

Here's my general version info:

```
"branch-cordova-sdk": "^2.6.24",

li packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 
local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
ios-deploy        : 1.9.2 
ios-sim           : 6.1.2 
Node              : v8.11.1
npm               : 5.6.0 
OS                : macOS Sierra
Xcode             : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b 
Environment Variables:

ANDROID_HOME : /Users/j/Library/Android/sdk
```

A couple of answers to Aaron's comments:

- These platform calls are in app.component.ts.
- I am printing the data in the init callback.
- The link data is never cleared unless I swipe away the app and relaunch. It is consistently called when navigating away from and back into the app.
- Both getLatestReferringParams() and getFirstReferringParams()  return no data with my non-branch link.
- Branch links (I created a quick link) behave as expected. The data callback is invoked once when I click the link and the app opens, and is no longer invoked on subsequent resume.

Comment: Is this only on Android? Are you printing the data in the init callback? Are these platform calls from the `app.component.js` files? Is the deep link data ever cleared out? After relaunch? Have you tried using the getLatestReferringParams() method? What happens with a regular Branch link?

Comment: Aaron from Branch here by the way. Please reach out to support@branch.io if you aren't able to resolve. We may need to take a closer look at your specific app.

Comment: Hey Aaron, I updated the question with a few more details. I can't test in iOs currently, we have yet to modify our existing iOs app to create a non-branch link to our Ionic app. If you would like to move this over to branch support, I can do that just let me know. Thanks.